# Dynamics 365 Data sync from On Premise SQL Server

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I need to sync the contact entity from an on premise master database. There is a SQL query that retrieves the contact information from different tables.
A nightly job add/update the contacts in D365 contact entity.
I am planning to write a console application/Windows service (SDK) and host it on-premise.
The prototype is updating the contact entity without an issue.
Trying to see if there is a better way of doing it especially without a third party tool.
Note: I can't use Kingwaysoft because of policy restrictions.

Comment: it's onpremise, you already wrote the code and you can't use a 3rd party tool. I don't see any reasons to complete it, I will just make sure the authentication is ok as older types (like office365 auth) are deprecated

Comment: I am continuing my development using SDK  ServicePricipal (as WS-Trust is already disabled for us). Someone told me that I could do the data sync using some connectors but didnt give the specifics. I have to develop various datasync jobs.